# Summing contents of a list inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say I have a list inside a list that looks like this: `List[List] like [date, views]` **entries** Example: entries = [['17.14.11','7224515'],
['17.14.11', '1053632'], ....]  I would like to make a dictionary where I include the sum of all views on the same day so it would look like:

```
{17.14.11: 8278147,.........}
```

I've tried doing the following

```
def total_views_per_day(entries: List[List]):
    for item in entries:
        if item[0] == entries[0]:
            item[1] += item[1]
    return item
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: very insightful

Comment: The instructions there explain what your question is missing better than I ever could. It's a lot. These instructions were given when you first posted the question. Please don't ignore them. The page on [Mcve] might also help

Comment: I dont think my question is any worse understood for writting Ive instead of I've

Comment: @DanielHao When I try running it gives me this error :ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'count'

Comment: Do you try different inputs than mine?  Can you share?

Comment: @DanielHao No I solved the issue, I had inside the dictionary [date,views] included but I excluded it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve it, here is the simple dictionary to sum the counts of each day.  Use the `date` as the `key` to add up each day:

```
entries = [['17.14.11','7224515'], ['17.14.11', '1053632'],
           ['17.14.12','12345'], ['17.14.12', '34556']]

def total_views_per_day(entries):
    ans = {}
    
    for date, count in entries:
        if date not in ans:
            ans[date] = int(count)
        else:
            ans[date] += int(count)
           
    return ans
    
print(total_views_per_day(entries))
```

Output:

```
{'17.14.11': 8278147, '17.14.12': 46901}
```